# How to get Facebook login button while using the server-side oauth flow?

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-login

I am handling the authentication using the server side oauth flow. All that is working fine, but how do I get the Facebook Login button to show up, just the image without any logic!

PS: Is this possible without some hack like saving the fb login image and calling the image itself? Also, if it matters, I am doing all this in python-django

Comment: you mean the similar used by SO for google/yahoo login??

Comment: I am not sure about your question. But I just need the standard fb login button which is part of the social plugins without it having to do anything as I am handling it all by server-side oauth flow. Just the image. Am i clearer?

Comment: that means you just need the button without any logic embedded in to the button click.am i understanding it right??

Comment: yes you are right, and this will be wrapped into my <a></a> so i could basically link it.

Comment: Ok!! in that case my approach will be to use firebug see what classes they have used and image and just a small `css` and button should be there.I just saw there css and html here is what they have done `<a class="fb_button fb_button_medium"<span class="fb_button_text">login</span></a>` and the are using a generic image just resizein it using css trick :)

Comment: Thanks, it works! You can post that as the answer/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Posting comment as an answer*

In that case my approach will be to use firebug see what classes they have used and image and just a small css and button should be there.I just saw there `css` and `html` here is what they have done

```
<a class="fb_button fb_button_medium">
<span class="fb_button_text">login</span>
</a>
```

and the are using a generic image just resizing it using `css` trick :)

Comment: I think something has changed because this doesn't seem to be working anymore.

Comment: @lechuck: there has been few changes in facebook, but i am not aware of that

Comment: We were using this as well and it seems to have stopped rendering the button at some point in recent days, though the link still works it no longer appears as a button.